# Javascript Object: iterating over properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, iteration

I have a variable, which, when printed to console, looks like this:

```
Object { PK-34={...}, PK-35={...}}
```

I'm adding a size method to this variable:

```
Model_value.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
```

This method returns 0, and iterating over those properties using:

```
for (foo in Model_value)
{
  //...
}
```

does not work.

How would I iterate over those PK-34, PK-35 properties?

Comment: @Tim sorry about code formatting. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `size` ends up being zero, apparently the object in question is *inheriting* those properties from its prototype. In that case, it means you don't want the `hasOwnProperty` check.

Example:

```
var Model_value = {};
Model_value.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
Model_value.sizeInherited = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
      size++;
    }
    return size;
};

function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype["PK-34"] = {
  name: "I'm PK-34"
};
Foo.prototype["PK-35"] = {
  name: "I'm PK-35"
};

display("Model_value.size(new Foo()) = " + Model_value.size(new Foo()));
display("Model_value.sizeInherited(new Foo()) = " + Model_value.sizeInherited(new Foo()));

var f = {
  "PK-34": {name: "I'm PK-34"},
  "PK-35": {name: "I'm PK-35"}
};

display("Model_value.size(f) = " + Model_value.size(f));
display("Model_value.sizeInherited(f) = " + Model_value.sizeInherited(f));

var bar = new Foo();
bar["PK-36"] = {name: "I'm PK-36"};

display("Model_value.size(bar) = " + Model_value.size(bar));
display("Model_value.sizeInherited(bar) = " + Model_value.sizeInherited(bar));
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ulipi5/2)

In the first case (`new Foo()`), the new object created by `Foo` has no properties of its own (only inherited ones) and so `size` ends up being `0` whereas `sizeInherited` is `2` (because it inherits two properties from its prototype).

In the second case, because `f` has its *own* `PK-34` and `PK-35` properties, its `size` is `2`. It inherits no properties from its prototype, and so `sizeInherited` is also `2`.

In the third case, `bar` has both two inherited properties and one property of its own, so `size` is `3` and `sizeInherited` is `2`.

---

**Update**: The edit seems to change the question a bit. If you're trying to iterate over the properties **in** `Model_value`, then you don't want to accept an argument, you want to use `this`:

To find how many *own* properties it has:

```
Model_value.size = function() {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
```

To find how many properties *total* it has (including inherited ones):

```
Model_value.size = function() {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in this) {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
};
```

Example:

```
function Model() {
}
Model.prototype["PK-34"] = {
  name: "I'm PK-34"
};
Model.prototype["PK-35"] = {
  name: "I'm PK-35"
};

var Model_value = new Model();

Model_value.size = function() {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
};

Model_value.sizeInherited = function() {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in this) {
      size++;
  }
  return size;
};

display("Model_value.size() = " + Model_value.size());
// ^-- returns 2 ("size" and "sizeInherited")

display("Model_value.sizeInherited() = " + Model_value.sizeInherited());
// ^-- returns 4 ("PK-34", "PK-35", "size", and "sizeInherited")
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ulipi5/3)

Note that the functions we've added to `Model_value` are assigned to properties, and so they show up in the totals.

Comment: Cheers! It makes sense now. Plus the impressive array of "related" links on the right hand side - enough to get my head around js. Thank you so much for the prompt response!

Comment: @Val Redchenko: No worries, glad that helped.